# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() returns null when called from @ControllerAdvice class

Tags: spring, controller, modelattribute, modelandview

In my current spring project, I have this class which should provide some modelAttributes to several views, from different controllers:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Model {
  @Autowired
  private CategoriaService categoria;

  @Autowired
  private ProdutoService produto;

  @Autowired
  private UsuarioService usuario;

  @Autowired
  private CredencialService credencial;

  @ModelAttribute("categorias")
  public List<Categoria> categorias() {
    return categoria.select();
  }

  @ModelAttribute("produtos")
  public List<Produto> produtos() {
    return produto.select();
  }

  @ModelAttribute("usuario")
  public Usuario usuario() {
    return usuario.findBy("username", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
  }

  @ModelAttribute("credenciais")
  public List<Credencial> credenciais() {
    return credencial.select();
  }
}
```

Right now, I have views distributed in 2 classes:

```
@Controller
public class Home {
...
}
```

which have views for public pages, like `/`, `/signin` and `/signup`. And:

```
public abstract class Controller<E> {
  private Class<E> clazz;

  @Autowired
  protected Service<E> serv;

  public Controller(Class<E> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  ...
}
```

a generic class which defines mappings to operations over the model layer classes, like insert, update and remove. Some model classes extend this class with their own mappings.

Right now, when I try access some of this extended methods (using `XMLHttpRequest`), I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.loja.Model.usuario(Model.java:43) ~[classes/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:142) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:869) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:132) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

where the line 43 corresponds to:

```
return usuario.findBy("username", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
```

One of methods causing this error when called is:

```
  @RequestMapping("download/{id}")
  @ResponseBody
  public byte[] download(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) throws IOException {
    return this.serv.download(id);
  }
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The SecurityContext returns NULL for getAuthentication() if no authentication is present. Make sure that your application can handle this if you merge code for public and non-public pages.

> Returns: the Authentication or null if no authentication information is available

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html#getAuthentication--